# Replace only the first character that appears in every line using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, replace

I have a string like this one:

```
AAA;BBB;CCC
DDD;EEE;FFF
AAA;PPP;GGG
```

And I would like to transform it to something like this:

```
AAA.BBB;CCC
DDD.EEE;FFF
AAA.PPP;GGG
```

With this regex, I can take the first group until the desired character to replace:

```
^([^;]*?)\s*;\s*
```

And with this, I think that I can replace it:

```
$1. '
```

But I do not know how could I code that in my script...

**Note:** It should work for every line of my string.

Comment: Can't you just limit the replace function to only replace the first occurence?

Comment: @JvdV that could not work, because I have to do that for every line of the string

Comment: `re.sub(r'^([^;]*?)\s*;\s*', r"\1. '", text, flags=re.M)`

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use `str.replace()`? It has parameter `count` that defines how many appearances should be replaced.

```
>>> 'AAA;BBB;CCC'.replace(';', '.', 1)
>>> 'AAA.BBB;CCC'
```

Comment: It only works for the first appearance, not for every line

Comment: @aldegalan apply it to every line then

Answer (score -1):

If you want to stick to a regex then you can use

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(';', '.', 'AAA;BBB;CCC', count=1)
'AAA.BBB;CCC'
```

Or simply use `str.replace` as suggested in another answer!